# Beginner Java Programmer Struggling (no line found)

Tags: java

The goal is is to ask what the capitol is of each state, state whether right or wrong, and then give total number of correct answers at the end. When compiling it gives me no errors, but when i try to run it it says:
java.uitl.NoSuchElementException:
No line found (in java.util.Scanner)

There are probably more errors then just this one, but i would rather just focus on this one first. Any feedback would be appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
 import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class States
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws java.io.IOException
     {
        Scanner inputt = new Scanner (System.in);
        String[][] cs = new String [50][1];
        while (true)
        {
            String in = " ";
            boolean ans = false;
            int tally = 0;
            int count = 0;
            load(cs);
            in = input(count, cs);
            ans = check(in, count, cs);
            if (ans == true)
            {
                tally ++;
                continue;
            }
            count= count +2;
            if (count > 100)
            {
                System.out.println("The count of correct answers is " + tally + ".");
                break;
            }
        }//end main method while loop
     }//end main method
    public static void load(String[][] cs)
    throws java.io.IOException
    {
       String filName = " ";
       filName = "C://Users/Troy/Documents/Class Documents/CSC 225/StateCapitals.txt";
       Scanner inputt = new Scanner(new File(filName));
       for (int row = 0; row < cs.length; row ++)
       {
           for (int col = 0; col < cs[row].length; col ++)
           {
           cs[row][col] = inputt.nextLine();
        }
        }//end for loop
        inputt.close();
    }//end load method
    public static String input(int count, String[][] cs)
    {
        Scanner inputt = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the capital of " + cs[count][0] + "? -");
        String t = inputt.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
        return t;
    }//end input method
    public static Boolean check(String in, int count, String [][] cs)
    {
      boolean correct = false;
      if (cs[count +1][0].compareTo(in)==0)
      {
          correct=true;
          System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
        }
       else
       {
         System.out.println("The correct answer should be " + cs[count + 1][0]);
        }
        return correct;
    }//end check method
}//end class
```

Comment: Please show the entire exception stacktrace text, and indicate for us which line throws the exception.

Comment: Whenever the java runtime encounters such an error, it spits out multiple lines of information that are extremely useful in figuring out where the problem occurred.  It is called a "stack trace", and it tells you (usually) the exact class and source code line number that was executing when the error occurred (and which method called it, and which method called IT, etc).  Be sure to include that in any SO question you ask, AFTER you have examined it to see if you can find your own error.  If you're going to program in Java, you're going to need to know how to do this.

Comment: Does the file `StateCapitals.txt` contain 102 lines? If not, then you have the source of your problem. ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29))

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at States.load(States.java:47)
 at States.main(States.java:21)
I believe this is what you are talking about, if not let me know. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong since i'm following exactly what i did in another program and just changing the variables and .txt file.

Comment: Alright i ended up fixing that, but now it won't go past Alabama (the first state) and even if i give the correct answer it states "the correct answer is ..." when it should just say "answer is correct...".

Comment: `if (cs[count][1].compareTo(s1)==0)` s1 is set to `" "`. So a whitespace will be the correct answer, always. Maybe rethink the `check` method.

Comment: Arlight, i now have the no line error fixed and it not telling between the correct and wrong answer fixed. The only thing that is left is it not moving past Alabama.

Comment: updated code in the question

Comment: I ended up fixing everything and getting it to work. Thank you Tom, you ended up helping me a lot. And thanks to everyone else who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading in your file correctly using the scanner class in the beginning of your load method.

Try using something like this

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a file");        
JFileChooser input = new JFileChooser();
int a = input.showOpenDialog(null);
String file = "";

if (a == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = input.getSelectedFile();
    file = selectedFile.getPath();
}

//use file input to read in line one at a time
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the Scanner class you could use something like this

```
// Location of file to read
File file = new File("data.txt");

try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    scanner.close();
} 

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```